# Calculating the frequency counter of all the unique values of a nested field

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want to find the frequency counter of all unique values of a nested field in Mongo Document.

To be more specific, if my collection say db['sample'], consists of the following documents -

```
{'a' : 1, 'b' : {'c' : 25, 'd' : "x", 'e' : 36}},

{'a' : 2, 'b' : {'c' : 5, 'd' : "xx", 'e' : 36}},

{'a' : 33, 'b' : {'c' : 25, 'd' : "xx", 'e' : 36}},

{'a' : 17, 'b' : {'c' : 25, 'd' : "xxx", 'e' : 36}},
```

how can I get the frequency counter of all unique values for the field 'd' ? i.e. my output should be {'d' : { "xx" : 2, "x" : 1, "xxx" : 1} }

Is this even possible ? Appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

I looked up the documentation for aggregation and objectToArray transformation to convert the map to array and tried the following in PyMongo

1)

```
db['sample'].aggregate([ { "$addFields" : { "b" : {"$objectToArray" : "$b"}}},\
                         {"$unwind" : "$b"},\
                         {"$group" : { "_id" : "$b.k",\
                                       "count" : {"$sum" : "$b.v"}}} ])
```

This gives the cumulative count of each of the fields where it it possible - 'c' : 25 + 5 + 25 + 25 for example.

2)

```
db['sample'].aggregate([ { "$addFields" : { "b" : {"$objectToArray" : "$b"}}},\
                         {"$unwind" : "$b"}, \
                         {"$group" : { "_id" : "$b.k", \
                                       "count" : {"$sum" : 1 }}} ])
```

This gives the total number of times the fields are present in the document - 'c' : 4, 'd' : 4 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically approaching this the wrong way around. You have a clear path to `"b.d"` as the key you want to aggregate on, there is no need to convert this to an array:

```
cursor = db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$b.d",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
     "_id": None,
     "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])

for doc in cursor:
  print(doc)
```

Returns

```
{ 'x': 1, 'xx': 2, 'xxx': 1 }
```

But that is actually overkill, since in reality all of the work was done in that initial [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement. All you really need to do is run that and fetch the results and combine them into a single dictionary as the desired output:

```
cursor = db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$b.d",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])

data = list(cursor)

result = reduce(
  lambda x,y:
    dict(x.items() + { y['_id']: y['count'] }.items()), data,{})

print(result)
```

Which returns exactly the same thing:

```
{ 'x': 1, 'xx': 2, 'xxx': 1 }
```

Moreover it does so without the *gymnastics* required by adding the other aggregation stages and operators, and you did not change what really comes back from the server since the initial [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) response is basically:

```
{ "_id" : "xxx", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "xx", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "x", "count" : 1 }
```

So the real lesson here is whilst *you can* do fancy manipulation within an aggregation pipeline, what you really should be considering is you *probably should not* when the alternative is cleaner and much more readable code.

For reference though all that happens is the additional [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) uses [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to create an array with `k` and `v` keys as would be expected in the next pipeline stage. Where that next stage uses [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to take the output of [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) from that array created in the previous stage, and basically transforms that into an Object/Dictionary.

By contrast, the `reduce` is doing exactly the same thing. We basically take the cursor results into a `list` so python functions can act on that list. Then it's just a matter of traversing the doucments in that list which always have `_id` as the key and another named property for the "counted" output ( here we used `count` ) and simply transforming those as the **key** and **value** pairs for the final dictionary output.

---

Just for fun, something based off of your initial attempts might be:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "b": { "$objectToArray": "$b" } } },
  { "$unwind": "$b" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$b.k",
      "k": "$b.v"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }

  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "data": { "$push": { "k": { "$toString": "$_id.k" }, "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } 
  }}
])
```

Which would return:

```
{ "_id" : "c", "data" : { "25" : 3, "5" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : "e", "data" : { "36" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : "d", "data" : { "xxx" : 1, "xx" : 2, "x" : 1 } }
```

Again, the same result without the additional pipeline stages to transform comes from using `map` and `reduce` with python:

```
cursor = db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "b": { "$objectToArray": "$b" } } },
  { "$unwind": "$b" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$b.k",
      "k": "$b.v"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.k", "v": "$count" } }
  }}
])

data = list(cursor)


result = map(lambda d: { 
  '_id': d['_id'],
  'data': reduce(lambda x,y: 
    dict(x.items() + { y['k']: y['v'] }.items()), d['data'],
  {})
},data)
```